# Can't instantiate a linkedlist of an interface as a linkedlist of a class that implements the interface

Tags: java, linked-list, type-mismatch

I have:

`LinkedList<Interface> fred = new LinkedList<Class>();`

where Interface and Class are the names of the interfaces and classes respectfully, but java gives me a type mismatch error. My class implements the interface and successfully contains all the functions called for by the interface.

Why does this not work?

Comment: just do `LinkedList<Interface> fred = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Because that isn't allowed. Nor is it clear why you would want to. `LinkedList<Interface> fred = new LinkedList<>();` and `fred` can take instances of any class which implements `Interface`. Your way, how would someone with a `LinkedList<Interface>` that's passed to them know it can only contain `Class` instances (or it's going to fail at run-time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
LinkedList<Interface> fred = new LinkedList<>();
```

The below is not valid as the type of `T` must be the same both on the left and right-hand side and clearly, this is not the case.

```
LinkedList<Interface> fred = new LinkedList<Class>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
LinkedList<MyInterface> fred = new LinkedList<>();
```

The recommended approach is:

```
List<MyInterface> fred = new LinkedList<>();
```